# Remember the order facets where selected

Tags: search

The search API stores facets with a key and the URL is usually something like

`?f[0]="facet_0&f[1]="facet_1"&f[2]="facet_2"`

Unfortunately, this array is rebuilt on each page load and the order is not preserved. I need to know the order the user selected the facets.

I am thinking about trying to ensure this filter array preserves the order but I might have to instead add a new key called 'facet_order' that does this if I can't modify the original filter key.

I have not been able to find a way to do either of these though. Is there a form alter or preprocess function that would allow me to change this behavior?

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: The order matters because as the user filters down into content, the most recent item selected is shown in the highlighted block where the user can see detailed information about the filter. As an example, if the last filter I selected was a US president, then there is a block that shows the birth and death year, short description, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ever needs to know how to do this here is how I got it to work. My URLs could become quite long if many filters are selected but I think that is okay for what I am doing.

I welcome any alternative recommendations or suggestions if you have any.

```
function my_theme_preprocess_facets_item_list__links(&$variables) {

  $ordered_key = 'fo';

  $facets_ordered = \Drupal::request()->query->get($ordered_key, []);

  foreach ($facet->getResults() as $facet_item) {
    $curr_url = $facet_item->getUrl();
    $curr_fo = $facets_ordered;
    $node_value = $facet_item->getRawValue();
    if($facet_item->isActive()) {
      if (($key = array_search($node_value, $curr_fo)) !== false) {
        // Remove this facet option from the current list
        unset($curr_fo[$key]);
        $curr_fo = array_values($curr_fo); // Reset the array values to be numerically sequential
      }
    } else {
      // Add the new filter the beginning of the ordered filter array so that the latest filter is always at pos 0
      array_unshift($curr_fo, $node_value);
    }
    $query_options = $curr_url->getOption('query');
    $query_options['fo'] = $curr_fo;
    $curr_url->setOption('query',$query_options);
  }
}
```

As a note, if you have sort filters then you will need to add this as a hidden form field like is done in the `search_api.module` in the function `search_api_form_views_exposed_form_alter` in the preserve filters if statement.

As an additional note, if you are using the facet summary module, you will also need to add a similar code snippet like above in `my_theme_preprocess_facets_summary_item_list`

I didn't need mine to work in Ajax and so I have not tested it with that.